# Laravel - Select in select in query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

How can I make in Laravel Querybuilder Select in selected data?

I have

```
DB::table('notifuserdoc')->select('nud_user', 'nud_document', 'name', 'surname', DB::raw('count(nud_id) as count'))
            ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'notifuserdoc.nud_user')
            ->groupBy('nud_user', 'nud_document')
            ->having('count', '>', 1)
            ->get();
```

which return data like:

[image]

But now, I want just write out user name and number of rows:

```
User 1 - 1
User 2 - 6
User 3 - 3
```

How can i get this result with Query builder?

** **EDIT:** **

**I found the sollution:**

```
$sub = DB::table('notifuserdoc')->select('nud_document', 'nud_user', DB::raw('count(nud_id) as dc'))
            ->whereNotNull('nud_user')
            ->groupBy('nud_user', 'nud_document')
            ->having('dc', '>', 1);

$other = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )->select(
        'nud_user',
        'name', 
        'surname',
        DB::raw('count(dc) as count')
    )
    ->mergeBindings($sub)
    ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'sub.nud_user')
    ->groupBy('nud_user')
    ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: How are your eloquent models and relationships specified in code?

Comment: @henrik For this table I dont have Model. Its just tracking table, and I dont create Models for tables which I use only on on one place. Now I just need make statistics. But if it will help me get, what I want, I can define relationships.

Comment: I would highly recommend it

Comment: @henri I found sollution without the relationships. But thanks